# Old Generation memory increases when using ThreadLocal

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have class `Collector` and `ThreadLocalScope` like this:

```
Collector {
    Collector() {
        events = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    add(Event e) {
        events.add(e);
    }

    flush() {
        LinkedList<Event> copy = events;
        new Thread(() -> {
            for (Event e : copy) {
                sendToServer(e);
            }
            copy.clear();
        ).start();

        events = new LinkedList<>();
    }
}

ThreadLocalScope {
    public static ThreadLocal<Collector> local = new ThreadLocal<>() {
        protected Collector initialValue() {
            return new Collector();
        }
    }
}
```

`Collector` simply adds events and when `flush` is called sends those events to an API in a new thread. The `Collector` is initialized in a [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).

I also have a Job class which is executed several times (using Quartz). When defined like this everything works great:

```
Job {
    execute() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100,000; i++) {
            ThreadLocalScope.get().add(new Event());
        }
        ThreadLocalScope.get().flush();
    }
}
```

However if instead I hold onto Collector like this:

```
Job {
    Collector collector;
    Job() {
        collector = ThreadLocalScope.get();
    }

    execute() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100,000; i++) {
            collector.add(new Event());
        }
        collector.flush();
    }
}
```

I see my Old Generation Memory usage increasing rapidly and Stop-the-world Garbage Collection cycles happening all the time. The only difference is I have added `Collector` as a member variable rather than calling `ThreadLocalScope.get()` every time.

The increase could only mean that the Events are being moved into Old Generation. But why would that happen? `Collector` immediately clears all its references to the Events, so even if it is not GCed, the events should be.

Answer (score 0):

I said:

> I think you might have a thread-safety issue here.

Incorrect.  I think it is simpler than that.

In the first version you are calling ThreadLocalScope.get() in the context of the thread that is executing the job.

In the second version you are calling ThreadLocalScope.get() in the contrext of the thread that is creating the `Job()` object.  It is then squirreled away in a variable and used later in the executor thread.  Assuming that the `Job()` objects are all created on the same thread, that means that your `execute()` methods share the same Collector object.  And they are potentially running on different threads.  Since `Collector` is not thread-safe, that is a hazard.

There is another thing that you might not be aware of.  It is likely that Quartz is using a thread pool.  That means that when an `execute()` call terminates, the thread goes back to the pool.  Next time around, if Quartz uses the same thread, it will reuse the `Collector` object from last time.

Comment: ThreadLocal means only one thread can access that variable. So each thread has its own `Collector` instance.There can be no race condition correct?

Comment: yes Quartz reuses the thread. But I verified the job creation and execute() works on the same thread. Resuing Collector is not an issue for the next job since in flush I clear the events

Comment: Still, I think that this is at the root of your problem.  And to be honest, the thread local is not helping efficiency, and `flush()` creating threads like that is a big performance hit.

Comment: Agreed there are some perf issues, but this job runs once every 3 minutes. But what Im really after is a possible explanation for the events being moved into Old Generation